# What font file formats are supported on the Amazon Silk Browser?

Tags: css, fonts, amazon-silk

Trying to get a font style to work on the [Amazon Silk Browser](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/silk/latest/developerguide/introduction.html). Went through their [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/silk/latest/developerguide/user-guide.html) but they don't mention it anywhere.

Currently using **tiff** and **woff** because it's supported by all the major browsers listed on the [w3 Web Font support page](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_fonts.asp) (And it works fine on those, but not on amazon silk)

Anyone know where the information regarding supported font formats for the Silk browser can be found? Or know which will work?

Comment: Maybe they don't support custom fonts

Comment: maybe but i highly doubt that